# Multiple CSS selectors not working with jQuery css method

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying following code but it's not working. The selectors are all right (In console, both list items are displayed) but opposite to it, the CSS is applied to only first element. Why is it so?

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="c1">1</li>
    <li class="c2">2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a=$(".c1");
    var b=$(".c2");
    console.log(a, b);
    $(b, a).css("font-size", "20px");
});
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in js/jq, but may be `var a=$(".c1")[0]; var b=$(".c2")[0];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation for the [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) function, there's nothing suggesting that that *would* work.

If you want to combine two separate jQuery objects, you do that with the [`add` method](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
b.add(a).css("font-size", "20px");
```

Example:

```js
var a = $(".c1");
var b = $(".c2");
console.log(a, b);
b.add(a).css("font-size", "20px");
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="c1">1</li>
  <li class="c2">2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or, of course, use a [selector group](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping) when calling `$` a single time:

```
$(".c1, .c2").css("font-size", "20px");
```

```js
$(".c1, .c2").css("font-size", "20px");
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="c1">1</li>
  <li class="c2">2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok. But why does `$(a, b).click()` thing (i.e., events) work? Is this type of multiple selectors meant for events and not for other jQuery methods like `css(), hide()` ?

Comment: @VikasKumar: `$(a, b).click()` with the `a` and `b` above *wouldn't* work. Note that `$(a, b)` *isn't* "multiple selectors," it's multiple arguments to the `$` function. `$(".c1, .c2")` is a [selector group](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping) (loosely, "multiple selectors") presented as a *single* argument to the function.

Comment: Oh! I think you want to say I MUST NOT use a jQuery $ statement inside another $ statement? Is that right?

Comment: @VikasKumar: There are places you might use a jQuery object when calling a jQuery method, but not to combine the contents of the two jQuery objects. I suggest spending an hour or two reading through the jQuery API, it'll probably make things much clearer (and it really only takes that long).

Comment: One more general question. You seem very experienced web developer (you've answered my questions earlier too). I like working with Web Technologies but new generation is learning Android, iOS apps. Do you think Web development would stop in 2-3 years and all my hard work on Web tools will be wasted?

Comment: @VikasKumar: I have no idea, I'm not a good trend-spotter. But FWIW, I suspect not; the opposite, if anything: I think apps written with "web" technology (Cordova/PhoneGap, React native, etc.) will become more prevalent and higher-quality.

Answer (score 2):

You can select multiple element in a single query separated by comma

This should work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".c2, .c1").css("font-size", "20px");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer your question, but the fact that you're not taking advantage of the `class` element attribute. In your case, you named the two `li` class items differently, `.c1`, `.c2` respectively which is a bad practice unless you changed them to IDs and that would be reasonable.

You can just apply the same class name for the two items (i.e. `<li class="c"></li>`), then have the following statement:

```
$('.c').css('font-size', '20px');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the working code,

$(document).ready(function(){
    var a=$(".c1,.c2");
    console.log(a);
    $(a).css("font-size", "20px");
});
---> $(".c1, .c2").css("font-size", "20px");

Here is the simple syntax to use multiple selector classes −
$('E, F, G,....')

as per your code, 
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a=$(".c1");
    var b=$(".c2");
    console.log(a, b);
    $(b, a).css("font-size", "20px");
});
it is like this, so it's not working.........
---> $(".c1", ".c2").css("font-size", "20px");
```